# SQL - Trying to include a subquery in a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery

I'm trying to come up with a report that will give me a few variables, I need to know the practice, the amount of patients, and the amount of new patients related to the practice in a given month. Later on I will need to add additional variables

I'm trying to use the following query:

```
select practice, count(distinct appointment_id), 
(select count(distinct appointment_id) from Appointments 
  where Patient_Status = 'New Patient') 
from Appointments 
where ServiceDate between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-31' 
group by practice
```

Doing that gives me the following results:

| Practice | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Austin | 7150 | 556979 |
| Houston | 6175 | 556979 |
| Dallas | 8522 | 556979 |

column C (new patients) should be a lot smaller than column B (total patients) for each row, i.e. for the Austin row I would expect a value of 600-700 - but it seems like it's returning a really high aggregate value on each row.

What am I doing wrong? I'm fairly novice in SQL so would really appreciate the help

Comment: Your issue is unclear. Please provide both sample input and the expected result as tables.

Comment: Presumably your subquery is meant to be correlated.

Comment: It seems you just need a conditional count for your third column instead of the subquery, but it's not clear without further information.

Answer (score 0):

Your group by will not affect your subquery
either add a group by to your subquery as

```
select practice, count(distinct appointment_id), 
(select count(distinct appointment_id) from Appointments 
  where Patient_Status = 'New Patient'
  group by practice) 
from Appointments 
where ServiceDate between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-31' 
group by practice
```

or duplicate your appointment table like

```
select practice, count(distinct A.appointment_id), count(distinct B.appointment_id) 
  from Appointments A, Appointments B
  where B.Patient_Status = 'New Patient'
  and A.ServiceDate between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-31'
  and A.practice = B.practice
group by practice
```

The second approach is easier because in many cases you will also need to join your subquery and your main query

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just need to conditionally count the appointments, you don't need a sub-query for this just a *case expression*, does this give your expected results?

```
select practice, 
  count(distinct appointment_id) as Appointments,
  count(distinct case when Patient_Status = 'New Patient' then appointment_id end) as NewPatientAppointments
from Appointments 
where ServiceDate between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-31' 
group by practice;
```

Comment: yup this got me what I needed - thank you!